# How can i evaluate the time complexity of a mixed integer scheduling problem?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am solving a complex scheduling problem by formulating it as a mixed integer linear problem and using the branch-and-cut algorithm. I have several different input parameters which can be changed - for instance, the number of different demand orders, the number of workers and machines available.

Is there a way of deriving an expression in big O notation for the time complexity of the algorithm? Should I evaluate different input parameters separately (keeping others fixed), check how the solution times required when varying one input parameter change and try to fit a trendline?

Answer (score 0):

Big-oh complexity is not something that can be estimated empirically from test runs. It is a theoretical *worst-case* *asymptotic* bound. Many MIP models are NP-hard (exponential complexity, if not worse). If you want to prove yours is too, you need to find a polynomial-time reduction to a known NP-hard problem.

If you are just interested in "average" run times (which are software and hardware dependent), you need a sample of "representative" problem sizes. I don't think varying one dimension at a time is a safe bet, since there could be interactions among them.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. When you say polynomial time reduction, what do you mean exactly please?

Comment: Let's call your problem P, and let Q be some well known NP-hard problem. A PT reduction would let you take any instance of Q and create an equivalent instance of P with computational effort polynomial in the size of Q. "Equivalent" means P has a solution if and only if Q does, and a solution of P can be converted back (with polynomial effort) to a solution of Q. Assuming all that, if you can solve P with polynomial effort, you can solve Q with polynomial effort ... and thus (Q being NP-hard) prove that P=NP (win the Fields medal, become famous, ...).